# Command line - save sub-strings conditionally

Tags: command-line, grep

Can a command line utility save sub-strings conditionally in different files? I have a file (`file.txt`) with several lines like the following.

```
1/1_ABCD4.txt:20020711
1/1_ABCD10.txt:20020731
2/2_ABCD2.txt:20071103
2/2_ABCD5.txt:20071107
3/3_ABCD1.txt:20090225
3/3_ABCD3.txt:20090230
```

My goal is to save `20020711` together with `20020731` in file `1`, `20071103` with `20071107` in file `2`, and  `20090225` with `20090230` in file `3`?

I could extract the desired sub-strings after `:` with the following command, but would lose the reference digit by doing so:

```
$ grep -oP 'txt\:\K[A-Z0-9-]+' 'path/to/file.txt'

20020711
20020731
20071103
20071107
20090225
20090230
```

Is it possible to build three separate files with the first digit before `/` as target reference while using  command line? The destination might be the same directory like the original text file.

1. File:

```
20020711
20020731
```

2. File:

```
20071103
20071107
```

3. File:

```
20090225
20090230
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `awk`:

```
awk -F'[:/]' '{print $NF > $1}' file
```

We split the row using both `/` and `:` as separators. The last field (`$NF`)  is what to print, and the first field (`$1`) is the output filename.

---

After running for your test input file:

```
$ head 1 2 3
==> 1 <==
20020711
20020731

==> 2 <==
20071103
20071107

==> 3 <==
20090225
20090230
```

---

Also, depending on your data, it is good to add a condition before this action, to avoid printing to a file with a random name, in case we have more lines with different structure, the input could be dangerous.

A simple example, if we want to print only when the first field (the filename) has only digits:

```
awk -F'[:/]' '$1 ~ /^[0-9]+$/ {print $NF > $1}' file
```

Comment: it's not about awk, but the shell identifying that as a glob. E.g. in Bash with `failglob` enabled, `-F[:/]` would give an error, and with `nullglob` enabled instead, it'd just get silently dropped off. And zsh errors by default on a non-matching glob

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed s'~\([0-9]\)/[^:]*:\(.*\)~echo \2 >> \1~e' file.txt
```

```
$ cat 1
20020711
20020731
```

Comment: I would steer *well* clear of GNU `sed`'s `e` flag and commands. Here, if the input contained `reboot #1/:` for instance, it would call reboot. IOW, you're introducing arbitrary command execution vulnerabilities. It's also very inefficient as it runs one shell per line of input.